# YII SQL Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, yii

I have a huge list of IDs that i need to query through a table to find if those IDs are available in the table, if yes fetch its model.

Since there are few thousands of IDs this process is really slow as I'm using CActiveRecord::find() mothod

ex. `$book = Book::model()->find('book_id=:book_id', array(':book_id'=>$product->book_id));`

I even indexed all possible keys, still no improvement.
Any suggestions to improve the execution speed?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I dont understand, its $product->book_id an array of ids?

Comment: why don't you use `IN` clause and `->findAll`?? ... in single shot you'll get all records and make them a hash (by id) and use it.

Comment: @Asgaroth : im sorry, it loops through the array and at each iteration $product->book_id will hold a new value

Comment: @SuVeRa : can you please explain more on how to do it?

Comment: as onkarjanwa sugests, if you are processing thousands of records and you dont necessarily need the relational features, you are better off with something like mongodb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)
Make a list of book ids

```
foreach $product in Product-List
    $book_ids[$product->book_id] = $product->book_id;
```

Now query all Book models ( indexed by `book_id` )

```
$books = Book::model()->findAll(array(
    'index' => 'book_id',
    'condition' => 'book_id IN (' . implode(',', $book_ids). ')',
));
```

Integrate `$books` in your code, I believe you are looping through all products.

```
foreach $product in Product-List
    if( isset($books[$product->book_id]) )
        $model = $books[$product->book_id]
```

---

2) Another way (I am just assuming you have Product model)

in Product model add a relation to Book

```
public function relations() {
    .......
    'book'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Book', 'book_id'),
    .......
}
```

While retrieving your product list, add `'with' => array('book')` condition,  with any of CActiveDataProvider  or CActiveRecord ...

```
//Example
$productList = Product::model()->findAll(array(
    'with' => array('book'),
));

foreach( $productList as $product ) {
    .......
    if( $product->book != null )
        $model = $product->book;
    ......
}
```

with either way you can reduce SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

Better if you use schema caching because `Yii` fetches schema each time we execute a query. It will improve your query performance.

You can enable schema caching by doing some configuration in `config/main.php` file.

```
return array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CApcCache', // caching type APC cache
        ),

        'db'=>array(
            ...........
            'schemaCachingDuration'=>3600, // life time of schema caching
        ),
    ),
);
```

One more thing you can fetch specific column of the table that will improve performance also.

You can do it by using `CDbCriteria` with find method of `CActiveRecord`.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'book_id';
$criteria->condition = 'book_id=:book_id';
$criteria->params = array(':book_id'=>$product->book_id);
$book = Book::model()->find($criteria);
```

I would suggest you to use any `nosql` database if you are processing thousands of records if that is suitable.

Comment: I tried it but there was no much of an improvement. any other suggestions?

Comment: Even if you execute with a 'select' clause or not, want it anyways return an ActiveDataProvider?